# Google Script Spreadsheet range returns unidentified

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically, Im getting a spreadsheet from my drive and trying to read a range.
Logging its name works perfectly, Logging any information like sheet-names etc works fine, But when i try to do getRange("A1") or getDataRange() on a sheet, it returns unidentified. Im 100% sure the given range(es) have data in them, its like the script cant find it, or has no acces to it.

Please help. Thanks.
(If someone wants code to look at, just ask.)

Comment: I'd like to see the code.

Comment: And the spreadsheet that your getting A1.

Comment: Sandy Good, Heres the code:
Most of the code is still for the old version.
look at the docsspreadsheet variable part. Thats what the question is about
http://pastebin.com/MWWr8bzD

Comment: Kriggs : The spreadsheet is just a default spreadsheet containing lists A1 is saying "Folder"

Comment: You get a Range and then try to get a value out of that? You need first to use `getValue();` - `var files = sheet.getRange("A1");` and `var row = files[c];` in lines 52 trough 54. Is it in this line where it buggs out?

Comment: Minify your code while the error is still beeing reproducible, I bet you'll find the error by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `UiApp` Class is now deprecated as of December 11, 2014.  Existing scripts should still function through June 30, 2015.

[Google Sunset Schedule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset?utm_campaign=htmlser-1214&utm_source=gadbc&utm_medium=blog)

This may not be the problem with your code, but I'm guessing that sooner or later you'll need to change that code.

When I try to run the `myClickHandler()` function, I get an error on this line:

```
if(e.parameter["foldertextbox"] != ""){
```

The error states:

[image: Cannot Read Property]

The code dies at that point.  When I **VIEW** the **EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT**, the last line is this error:

> Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from
>   undefined. (line XXX, file "Code") [0.465 seconds total runtime]

So, I'm guessing there is something wrong with that line of code.  It looks like you are trying to get the value out of the text box named **foldertextbox** with an `e` event object property, but there seems to be something wrong with the syntax.  I can't find any documentation that supports `e.parameter["text box name"]`